# Test generic method of parent abstract class

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockito, spy

I have abstract class like this:

```
abstract class A(val x: String, y: String..){
fun <R1,R2>bla(request:R1):Response<R2>(..)
}
```

Also I have class that extends abstract:

```
class B(val bean1:Bean1, val bean2: Bean2): A(bean1.x, bean2.y){
fun doSomething(
  <R1,R2>bla(Object())
)}
```

My test looks like:

```
@Mock
private lateinit var bean1:Bean1
@Mock
private lateinit var bean2:Bean2
private lateinit b:B
@BeforeAll
fun init(){
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
 b = spy(B(bean1,bean2))
}

@Test
fun `Test`(){
 doReturn(Response()).when(b).bla<Class1,Class2>(Object())
}
```

How I can test method 'bla' without calling real implementation?
In case above, it calls real implementation every time. I tried to use mock instead spy, but result the same.

Halp!:)

Comment: You are not testing the method if you don't call the real implementation

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using interface instead abstract class.